# Spotify Play Button doesn't work for the "starred" playlist

Tags: spotify

I am having trouble getting the new feature released by Spotify, Play Button, to work on the starred playlist I use. When I use any other playlist it works just fine.

Example...

Works:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:joshua88wa:playlist:6U00tOjtzhBrEgpJJhTxDh" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:joshua88wa:starred" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Is there any way to get my starred playlist to work with this new feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starred playlists are not supported with the Spotify Play Button. The reason is because of how it is implemented in the backend. It puts too much load on our servers basically. We will fix this eventually, but for now, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference you can cite?

Comment: No, but I work at Spotify and built it, so you can cite me if you want :) I'll make sure someone updates the documentation with all the valid types. Right now it says "any song, album or playlist", which you noticed isn't very true.